# GPStracker code crash concept

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, gps

Good evening and good week. We run this script from tutorial but my crash concept does not make an error in the code. nor to the errors refer to a particular line code. Please for your help.

Tutorial: http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

```
01-26 15:36:06.751: I/Process(10528): Sending signal. PID: 10528 SIG: 9
01-26 15:36:18.251: D/AndroidRuntime(10613): Shutting down VM
01-26 15:36:18.251: W/dalvikvm(10613): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{pack/pack.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pack.MainActivity
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pack.MainActivity
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
01-26 15:36:18.251: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):    ... 11 more
01-26 15:41:18.281: I/Process(10613): Sending signal. PID: 10613 SIG: 9
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.pack"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

    <permission

        android:name="my.pack.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="my.pack.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="permission_name"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
   <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="My api key"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You full activity name (package + class) is not the same in manifest and code. There's `pack.MainActivity` declared in manifest but it is not found in code.

Comment: There is normally the name of the package. I have it switched off for publication.

Comment: Yes; still the class loader cannot find the activity class by name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. The control now and I update.